# Probability calculation: A figure moves on a line starting at the zero point..

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> A figure moves on a line starting at the zero point in integer steps,
>   randomly moving to right or left.
>
> 1. How many ways are there in $2n$ steps to get back to the zero point?
> 2. How many ways in $m$ steps are there in order to get from the zero point to point $k$?

I have taken both these tasks from an old exam because I found them very strange. I'm curious how they could be solved correctly, if they have been formulated correctly at all (probably yes since they were part of an exam..?).

For 1. it's important to keep in mind that we are dealing with integers and that we move in two steps, and we want get back to zero in these two steps moving.
That means we can only use even numbers (because we move in two steps), I think. But how to say "how many ways" there are? I have absolutely no idea : /

Comment: What do you mean by "integer steps"  ? Do you mean just one step to the left or one to the right?

Comment: @lulu ... -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, **0**, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, ...

Comment: But then the answer is infinite, even for $2$ steps.  You can always move right $k$ steps and then left $k$ steps.

Comment: @cnmesr Perhaps you mean either one unit to the left or one unit to the right?

Comment: @Nilknarf yes this

Comment: @cnmesr Does my post answer your question? :)

Comment: @Nilknarf Probably yes I'm still trying to understand problem 2. Thank you very much :D

Comment: @cnmesr Would you like me to explain it a little bit more for you?

Comment: @Nilknarf Maybe you can explain what is asked by the task in problem 2? How do you know what point $k$ is? This is so general I don't get it what is asked.

Comment: @cnmesr Okay, I'll explain further in my question.

Comment: @cnmesr Do you understand the part where I talked about when it is impossible or possible?

Comment: @Nilknarf No because I don't understand what is asked from the task :p

Comment: Oh. In the question, it is asking "if you have a point on the number line that is $k$ units away from $0$, how many ways are there to end up at that point using $m$ steps? "

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**PROBLEM 1:** In order for the figure to end where it started, $n$ of the steps must be to the left and $n$ must be to the right. Any walk of the figure can be written as a string of $L$s and $R$s. Thus the number of  paths described is the number of such strings with $n$ $L$s and $n$ $R$s, which is, of course,
$$\binom{2n}{n}$$

**PROBLEM 2:** This is not always possible. Consider the case $m=2$, $k=1$. It is possible if and only if $m$ is in the form $k+2n$, where $n$ is a positive integer. When it is possible, we will have to create a string with $k+n$ characters that are $L$ and $n$ characters that are $R$ in a string of $k+2n$ characters, or vice versa, and so the number of paths is
$$\binom{k+2n}{n}$$
or
$$\binom{m}{n}$$
if $m$ is in the form $m=k+2n$.